# NetCat - Send Files With Delay

Tags: file, delay, netcat

I'd like to know how to send multiple files from a directory with delay time (e.g. 10 seconds) using the Linux NetCat? I'm using a script like this:

```
COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -lt 101 ]; do 
    tar -c lda_wiki1w_$COUNTER | nc -i 10 localhost 2211
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

But the option `-i 10` doesn't work.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: -i applies between lines of text, I don't think it would apply within a tar file, or between distinct invocations of `nc`.  Perhaps you could just add a `sleep 10` to your loop?

Comment: Or see if your distro has `bfr` or `buffer` - there are probably other similar programs out there too..

Comment: I'll try use the `sleep`. Thanks!